# flash read err, 1000

Tags: serial, arduino-ide, electronics, esp32

I know this question has been asked multiple times but solutions giving there hasn't been working,

I've got an esp32 soldered to my own designed PCB board with a UART to USB converter all that is working fine, I can get connected to my esp from the Serial monitor.

But it prints every about 0.5s:

```
rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET)
boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT) 
flash read err, 1000 ets_main.c 
371 ets Jun 8 2016 00:22:57
```

Solutions have been to make sure to have 3.3v on the esp. I find it unlikely to have anything to do with it, 'cause its voltage range goes from 2.6v to 3.6v, but anyway I have tested it with an advanced transformer and a multimeter to check that there was 3.3v on the Vcc pin (didn't change anything).

All help would be appreciated.

Here is a bit more info:

I've also connected a 10uF capacitor (someone told me to try that).

If I pull IO0 to ground, it prints waiting for download in the serial monitor and I can almost upload the program, this is what I get:

[image]

> THERE IS NO CONNECTION BETWEEN NEIGHBORING PINS

(I have checked with multimeter)

PCB board:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide images of your custom PCB

Comment: I had this kind of error sometimes and it always seemed to be related to a broken flash in the esp32. Do you have anything connected to the SPI pins?

Comment: @SimSon could you explain what the SPI pins is? (sorry for my lack of knowledge)

Comment: The esp chip itself doesn't have an internal flash to store the program but uses an external flash instead. Communication with this flash happens via serial peripheral interface (SPI) which also is available on the esp's pins. Obviously you haven't connected anything except the serial lines.

Comment: How did you assemble the esp on that pcb? Reflow? Solder iron? I just wonder why the surface looks a bit demolished...

Comment: solder iron and flux, the "demolished" is left overs from the flux

Comment: @SimSon the tutorial on hooking up your esp with usb, does not need or contain any "SPI", but do i have to connect the SPI i pins to something? and does they only need to be connected during upload?

Comment: @MariusWanscher there's no need for anything like that, the esp is connected to the flash internally and its firmware/bootload manages everything

Comment: @MariusWanscher ok, I just couldn't see wether it was flux or the pcb might have become too hot during reflow. From my experience the flash is the least temperature-tolerant part inside the esp. Was flashing actually ever possible on this individual?

Comment: @MariusWanscher no, not the spi pins!

Comment: How do you actually flash it without having the flash- and reset-pins connected to your pcb? Also your pcb is missing pull-up resistors. Have you taken a look at a minimal circuit? https://www.14core.com/wiring-and-flashing-programming-esp-32-esp32s-with-usb-ttl-uart/?cn-reloaded=1

Comment: No, I haven't gotten it to fully flash, ArduinoIDE says that it has uploaded the whole program but afterwards, the serial monitor goes quiet, if I restart the chip(by pulling EN to ground) it just starts spitting out the ram 1000 err

Comment: I simply take a jumper cable and connect it with ground and touch either io0 or EN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the solution was to add a 10k pull-up resistor to the EN pin, as shown [HERE](https://www.14core.com/wiring-and-flashing-programming-esp-32-esp32s-with-usb-ttl-uart/?cn-reloaded=1)

No capacitor needed

Answer (score 0):

Your PCB is lacking in the majority of things you need to get the module working. These modules are not "simple" in that you provide power and forget about it. You must add all the *required* support components. Those support components are **NOT optional**. For example: you aren't setting the boot mode properly with the right pullups. You lack a capacitor on the power pins (I told you to add one already. Where is it?). Also your power traces are too thin. The impedance is too high.

Comment: there is a 10uF capacitor added, its the second black and red wire you see on the image, I have moved it directly on the power pins, still not working

Comment: and what do you mean by "I'm not setting the boot mode properly", serial monitor literally says it's in boot mode

Comment: There's many ways of booting the ESP32. You haven't selected one. Read section 2.4 "Strapping Pins" in the ESP32 datasheet.

Comment: And you can't have a decoupling capacitor on the end of a pair of wires. It makes it pointless. Solder it *directly* on to the power pins of the module. https://photos.app.goo.gl/rjTESshnQGQjjtmdA